# Best way to make a function that accesses a database table threadsafe?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

Basically what the title says. We have some critical data that will be read + updated in the same function, and we have to make sure that we can avoid a race condition. Will the @Transactional annotation take care of this?

```
// Both threads call this function
void someMethod() {
    int value = EntityObject.getSomeField();
    int newValue = modifyValue(value);

    // PROBLEM: The other thread read "someField" before the database was  updated, 
    // and we end up with the wrong value when both threads are done

    EntityObject.setSomeField(newValue);
    EntityObjectService.save(EntityObject);
}
```

We're using MySQL

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and add other necessary details to your question, such as the type of database you're accessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` annotation will help you in the database level, not with your application threads. If there's a concern that the old data should not been read by other threads while it's updating, I would use a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`:

Define in one of your configuration:

```
@Bean
public ReentrantReadWriteLock lock(){
    return new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
}
```

When updating in a class:

```
@Autowired private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

public void someMethod() {

    try {
        lock.writeLock().lock();

        // Do your read & lengthy update here

    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }   
}
```

And when other threads are accessing to read only:

```
@Autowired private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock;

public void someMethodThatReads() {

    try {
        lock.readLock().lock();

        // Do your reading here

    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }   
}
```